# Startup script to run detachted screen, switch user, and run multiple bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, debian, startup, gnu-screen

I want to create a small startup script that does multiple things in a row in a screen.

1. The script starts a named, detached screen (`screen -S discordbot -d -m` works)
2. The user inside the script is changed (Neither `screen -S discordbot -X "su discordbot"`, `screen -S discordbot -X su discordbot`, nor `screen -S discordbot -d -m bash -c "su discordbot;"` seems to work, or at least subsqeuent commands are not executed).
3. A `cd` folder change is exectuded.
4. A java jar or other script is started.

As I run multiple bots, the script needs to be able to do this in slight variation multiple times in a row. Any pointers on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

The screen session that you start up will exit as soon as the process that you *started* exits.

This works, for instance:

```
$ screen -S discordbot -d -m bash
```

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    2948.discordbot (Detached)
1 Socket in <...>
```

As does this:

```
$ screen -S discordbot -d -m bin/discordbot.sh
```

Where `bin/discordbot.sh` looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "Sleeping..."
sleep 10
/bin/echo -n "Hit enter to finish this script: "
read
```

The last two lines to prevent the screen from exiting prematurely. The other various things you want to do within that startup script should also work, assuming that you do this as `root` so that the `su` will work without prompting.